# Не получается установить модуль Phyton: "Фатальная ошибка в лаунчере: не удалось создать процесс с помощью '"'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Никак не могу установить модуль `xldr` на ноутбук. Сначала показывал "pip не является внешней или внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом", потом я установила путь к `pip` в переменные окружения. После всех проделанных действий модуль так и не установился, появилась новая ошибка:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'`. Помогите, пожалуйста: уже второй час бьюсь) 
У меня Windows 10

Comment: Попробуйте установку через `-m` чтобы путь воспринимался корректно. *python -m pip install --upgrade pip* или сам файл запустить через `-m`

Comment: Ничего не произошло... Может, так и надо?

Comment: сложно сказать. Проверьте установленный модуль. Если конфликтов версий нет, то должно быть всё корректно.